# Importing Algorthmia into React-Native but receiving "Module does not exist..." error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, algorithmia

I'm trying to include the Algorithmia client into my React-Native application and for some reason I keep hitting a "Module does not exist in the module map" error.  I've followed the suggestions in the error and have Cleared Watchman watches, deleted and reinstalled node_modules, Reset Metro Bundler Cache and Removed the haste cache and still no luck.

Is there something I'm overlooking or unaware of?

I followed steps for installation from the [Algorithmia docs](https://algorithmia.com/developers/clients/node/)

`npm install --save algorithmia`

and at the top of my AlgoComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Image, Dimensions, TouchableHighlight, Text } from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import Algorithmia from 'algorithmia';
```

other styles i've tried:

```
import * as Algorithmia from 'algorithmia';
import { Algorithmia } from 'algorithmia';
```

I've looked around quite a bit, but so far no luck.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Update: 1/16/2018** - I didn't quite grasp that React-Native isn't truly node, since it's compiling to Objective C and Swift (might not have said that exactly right, but thats the gist).  Maybe this is the issue I'm hitting since I was following the node docs?  In the meantime I've set up an express server that will sit between my Native App and Firebase and am planning to make the calls to Algorithmia from there.  I'll update as I get further along.

**Final Update: 3/19/2018** - Unless another way opens up, I've decided to continue using the express server routing I set up in January.  Seems to be working just fine.

Comment: 1-)Did you try `npm link algorithmia`?  2-)if nothing changes, did you try linking the module from Xcode or Android Studio? You know some of the modules need to manual linking. 3-) The last thing is in the document that you sent about module says use `var algorithmia = require("algorithmia");` for importing the library.